# APK compiled with JavaFXPorts does not work

Tags: android, apk, gluon, javafxports

I have been trying to get a sample HelloWorld JavaFX app to work on Android for a while.  I have managed to get past all the dependency issues etc and have compile the project into an APK with both JavaFXPorts and the new Gluon plugin.  However when I try and run my APK on an Android device it always says 'There was a problem parsing the package'.  Is there something I am doing wrong?  The project runs fine on the desktop.

I first managed to compile the project with IntelliJ using the Gluon plugin on Ubuntu.  However I have now moved to JavaFXPorts with Eclipse on Windows.  I managed to get the project compile using a Java 8 SDK but the results are still incompatible with my devices.  I am using Gradle to build the project and have been playing around with the buildToolsVersion, targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion.  But JavaFXPorts requires buildToolsVersion of at least 26.0.2.  I have an Android box with a Version string 6.0.1 and have been able to compile and run Android Apps created with the standard Android API v19 but no luck with JavaFX.